# Can't seem to connect with Wifi

Tags: release-hera, wifi, drivers, internet

I have installed Elementary OS 5.1.6 Hera, yesterday. I see all the wifi hosts but can't seems to connect with them. Passwords are alright. Ethernet connection seems to work fine.. need help.

Answer (score 0):

can you share some information about your router,is it dual band? Create a mobile hotspot and try connecting to it.

Comment: I made a mistake of deleting windows 7 and running a single OS (i.e Elementary) on my laptop and it was definitely a BAD decision (for a Noob like me). I need to install windows 10 as second OS and it seems the tutorials on youtube are no longer a help. Would you please tell  me how  install windows 10 in this OS ?

Comment: You want to dual boot or only want windows as your primary os? To dual boot download Windows iOS file and this app for https://www.balena.io/etcher/ Linux. Create a bootable USB by using that software and restart. On boot of laptop chopse that USB stick and you will see windows installer.